# Sort.by("title") vs (Sort.Order.by("title")) in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am wondering how `Sort.Order.by(String name)` works in Spring Data JPA.

Assuming we want to find all books and sort them by title using BookRepository extending `JpaRepository<Book, Long>`

I would create `PageRequest` for the `bookRepostitory.findAll(pageable)` as follows:

`bookRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0,10,Sort.by("title");`

But I saw also this solution and I can't find out, how it works.

`bookRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0,10, Sort.by(Sort.Order.by("title"));`

Could you please tell me what are the advantages of that second solution and how this works?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your case the two are equivalent. `Sort.by` is overloaded to accept a variety of combinations of `String`, `Direction` and `Order` objects.

`Order` is what is used internally and it simply combines a `String` for the the name of the property to sort by and a `Direction`, i.e. if to sort ascending or descending.

Using `Order` objects is the most flexible since it allows to sort by multiple  properties in different directions. The other overloads a shorter, but offer no or lesser control over the sorting direction.

[It is all in the source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.java) which is straight forward.